# Variations pages throw exceptions

Tags: 2010, variations

I am seriously sick because all of sudden variations pages have stopped working. I have no clue on how can I fix it :( See below:

[image: _/layouts/VariationLabels.aspx]

[image: VariationSettings.aspx]

Comment: Does this happen for every page? Sounds like your variations relationships table is screwed...

Comment: yes, this happens for every variations page. Do you have reasonable suggestion or solution to it?

Comment: Well there's a hidden list at the root of the sit ecollection that maintains mappings of pages in the root variation to all the others. Problem is, it's all GUIDs, I think. There might be tutorials on the web for rebuilding this mapping list.

Comment: Jamey, do you know any good ones?

Comment: Do you see this error on all site pages and what is the size of the Content DB?

Comment: Content Database is around 60MB and variations error occurs on every page that uses variations.

Comment: oh that's not quote big btw I suspect you might not be on production farm, are you?

Comment: it's a development server. Quite a mess at the moment!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, as you said, the size of your Content Database is not large (I assume you might also be not on production farm) therefore I would recommend you restoring the Content Database from any other server or backup source (Production) again.

Comment: Thanks Falak, I will try it but it is not Production Farm.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in tool `variationsfixuptool` that allow to self fix issues within that variation relationship hidden list.

```
stsadm -o variationsfixuptool
          -url <absolute web URL> 
         [-fix] 
         [-scan] 
         [-spawn] 
         [-showrunningjobs] 
         [-recurse] 
         [-label <label to fix or spawn>]
```

In your case that's the -fix that will be helpful as it will allow you to correct

- Missing Variation Group ID on source site or source page
- Missing relationships list entry for source or target page or site
- Missing Variation Group ID on target site or target page
- Different Variation Group ID in source site/page and target site/page

You also have the -scan switch to first get an overview of what could be broken.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Nope, it didn't help. I tried to run the scan/fix and but it throws **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** message

Comment: Did you check your variation labels and relationship list using a tool like SharePoint Manager 2010 (portable, doesn't require installation and lightweight) to check inside these two lists if you can spot a culprit (missing labels, etc.). Any backup that you could restore to check if it's an environment issue (timer jobs ?) or a content issue ?

Comment: SharePoint Manager was helpful but I couldn't figure out the what's culprit inside relationship list

Comment: You should ensure you have valid backup from now and 1. delete all non source variation labels & sites. Review the timer jobs entries for that web application to ensure all 4 the jobs are runnings and then check the variation logs within your site collection to find any culprit. You can also investigate your ULS and progressively recreate a new variation label (hierarchy will be created within 24h so you should force the job to run immediately). Removing as much content as possible (hence the backup) will help to spot the culprit(s)

Answer (score 0):

Can you look in the list:-

```
http://myhostname/_layouts/VariationLabels.aspx
```

and ensure the values look correct?

You should have the following fields present:-

Label

Display Name

Language

Locale

Is Source

Description

Heirarchy Is Created

Comment: I can't see the screen as you suggested. I got the same error messages as seen above.